# UIImage animation

Tags: iphone, uiimage

I have 6 uiimage plates which are placed on the view. Now I am rotating the images 90 degrees on double tap by using the below code:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 0.5);
plate.transform = transform;
```

For first double tap it rotates 90 degree but when double tap second time it doesn't rotate.
Am i missing something ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AffineTransform` keeps the data of the transformation saved. So if you `scale/rotate/move` the view, the `AffineTransform` will keep that info.

In order to rotate 90 degree each time, you will have to `get` the current value and then modify it, or just keep a variable of your current degree and change the variable.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are already there, you have already rotated those rads. Try by increwsing the rotation value everytime the user taps the image.